# The dbType NVarChar is invalid for this constructor

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

```
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void MyMethod()
    {
        string connectionString = "context connection=true";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlMetaData[] metaData = {
                                         new SqlMetaData("Column1", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar)
                                         ,new SqlMetaData("Column1", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar)
                                     };
            SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(metaData);
            record.SetString(0,"hello world");
            SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(record);
        }
    }
```

When I run the method in SQL

`EXEC MyMethod`

Error

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MyMethod, Line 0 A .NET
>   Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or
>   aggregate "MyMethod":  System.ArgumentException: The dbType NVarChar
>   is invalid for this constructor. System.ArgumentException:     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMetaData.Construct(String name,
>   SqlDbType dbType, Boolean useServerDefault, Boolean isUniqueKey,
>   SortOrder columnSortOrder, Int32 sortOrdinal)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMetaData..ctor(String name, SqlDbType
>   dbType)    at WcfClrApps.MyNamespace.MyMethod()

How can a return a record that I create myself?  I do not want to run any SQL.  Project build is set for .NET 3.5.  MSDN indicates 4.0 is not supported in SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: Is the problem the type choice, or is the problem that you haven't specified a length?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem is two fold.  1.  Max length is required.  2.  `SendResultsStart()`/`SendResultsEnd()` are required.

```
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void MyMethod()
    {
        string connectionString = "context connection=true";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlMetaData[] metaData = {
                                         new SqlMetaData("Column1", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)//Max length has to be specified
                                         ,new SqlMetaData("Column1", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)//same story
                                     };
            SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(metaData);
            SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart(record);//SendResultsStart must be called

            //create a row and send it down the pipe
            record.SetString(0,"hello world");
            SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(record);

            SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsEnd();//End it out

        }
    }
```

[Iterative example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlpipe.sendresultsrow.aspx)

Comment: For the specific error `The dbType NVarChar is invalid for this constructor` only adding the MaxLength parameter solves the problem. Turns out that when using SqlDbType.NVarChar, you must use the constructor which accepts the MaxLength parameter.

Comment: I am having this problem too. The type I want to use is `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. When I set the max length in the `SqlMetaData` constructor to `Int32.MaxLength` I get the error _Specified length '2147483647' is out of range._ What is the allowed max length?

Comment: @JamesFaix use -1 for max.  Even using Int32.MaxLength/2 leads to overflows.

Answer (score 3):

Never done anything this way, but wouldn't this work?

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void MyMethod()
    {
        string connectionString = "context connection=true";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlMetaData[] metaData = {
                                         new SqlMetaData("Column1", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
                                         ,new SqlMetaData("Column2", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
                                     };
            SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(metaData);
            record.SetString(0,"hello world");
            SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(record);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only difference I see is NVarchar to varchar. That's what I originally started with and the result is similar.

Comment: also changed the column name as I believe that would error, do you have more code for me to run unit tests with?